# How to rspec Rails Configuration class and the array it creates from a yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, rspec, mocking

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions how to rspec (mock) the Rails Configuration instance returned in my class below by the  `MyModile::Application.config` method call?

I understand how to mock out objects that are created within my class to be tested using something like:

```
let(:my_class_mock) { double("MyClass").as_null_object }
MyClass.stub(:new).and_return my_class_mock
```

But Application is not created within my class.
I want to mock out that is it called with myfile and return a mocked array so I can ensure its reading the correct values e.g. "url"

```
class ConfigReader
  def initialize
    my_conf = MyModile::Application.config.myfile 
    @url = my_conf["url"]
  end
end
```

**Edit:**
I forgot I had created an initializer like this:

```
EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH = "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/myfile.yml" config_file_exists = FileTest.exists?(EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH) 
case 
  when config_file_exists # if it does exist, load it 
    MyMobile::Application.config.myfile= YAML.load_file(EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH)[::Rails.env] 
  when !config_file_exists 
    raise "#{EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH} configuration file is missing" 
end
```

I will try and stub the YAML.load_file to see if I can return my own array mock.

Answer (score 2):

Does stubbing not solve your problem? You can stub on an existing Class eg

```
@my_conf = {:whatever_you_want => :goes_here}
MyModile::Application.config.stub(:my_file).and_return(@my_conf)
```

Comment: I think `stubs` is shoulda syntac, rspec is just `stub` and `and_return`.

Comment: Thanks, its complaining the method :my_file is undefined which is true this does not exist as a method in the Configuration class. I dont really understand the line that reads the config: MyModile::Application.config.myfile.  I understand this is calling the config method on the Application class and this method consists of: @config ||= Application::Configuration.new(find_root_with_flag("config.ru", Dir.pwd)) which is returning a new Configuration class but I don't see what the .myfile is actually doing. The line of code does actually read a file called myfile.yml

Comment: @nathanvda - probably just me writing he above my memory rather than checking if it's plural or not.

Comment: @Kevin - my example above is based purely on the example code you shown above. If calling "myfile" on Application.config is not what you want to test - then what do you want to test? Can you elaborate in your question please? (comments are very bad for structuring code)

Comment: I forgot I had created an initializer like this:

EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH = "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/myfile.yml"

config_file_exists = FileTest.exists?(EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH)
case
when config_file_exists
  # if it does exist, load it
  MyMobile::Application.config.myfile= YAML.load_file(EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH)[::Rails.env]

when !config_file_exists
  raise "#{EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH} configuration file is missing"
end

I will try and stub the YAML.load_file to see if I can return my own array mock.